# Table misalignment with position: absolute in IE (not Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am having an issue using position: absolute; across browsers.

In Chrome, the table looks fine. Everything is aligned. Please see the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhrAi.jpg

However, in IE (11) the top of the columns do not line up. Please see the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgSpB.jpg

I have the first column set to absolute so that it is fixed while scrolling horizontally. The scrolling action is fine in both browsers, but the aesthetics are off in IE.

Here is the style:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    }

.tg td{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    }

.tg th{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    }

.tg .tg-941l{
    background-color:#ffc000;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

.tg .tg-huo5{
    background-color:#ffc000;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

.tg .tg-Sidebar{
    background-color:#ffc000;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: absolute;
    }

.tg .tg-yw4l{
    vertical-align:top;
    }
</style>
```

And here is the beginning of the table with the first td:

```
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 1290px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 100px">
<col style="width: 58px">
<col style="width: 181px">
<col style="width: 62px">
<col style="width: 68px">
<col style="width: 42px">
<col style="width: 76px">
<col style="width: 52px">
<col style="width: 79px">
<col style="width: 67px">
<col style="width: 95px">
<col style="width: 90px">
<col style="width: 668px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th height="33" width="90" class="tg-Sidebar"><b>Assembly</b></th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">P/N</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">CPU</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">RAM</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Compact flash</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">VDC input</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Power supply</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Ignite Online</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Introduced</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Last shipped</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">History</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Field replacement</th>
    <th class="tg-huo5">Notes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

      <td height="49" width="90" class="tg-Sidebar"><b> BC-700 </b></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">50639</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Intel Celeron, 400 MHz or VIA C3, 733 MHz</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">256 MB</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1GB</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">5</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">50652, 50893, or 51146</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">No</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2005</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">5/1/2009</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Obsolete. Replaced by BC-710.</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">BC-711 and power supply</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Original mid-end M86.</td>

  </tr>
```

Any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: As you have assigned width values to every column the table becomes less responsive across browsers, try using percentages for width instead. e.g. width: 10% instead of width:129px.

Comment: I will try this now. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: No problem, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I am going to continue changing the point values to percentages for conformity; however, there is still an offset at the top of the table. With position set to relative, the top border is flush on all browsers (IE, Chrome and FF). When set to absolute, only IE has the issue.  [link](http://i67.tinypic.com/1ph3it.jpg)

Comment: I will test your code, see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the full table code: [link](http://pastebin.com/fTPrqabU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove 'position: absolute' from the style class '.tg .tg-sidebar'. The position style is not needed in order for the table to be responsive.

Comment: I add the absolute so that the first column is fixed during a horizontal scroll.

Comment: When I remove border-collapse: collapse; from the .tg style this seems to fix the issue with the box proportions.

Comment: I will try that now and let you know!

Comment: May I ask which version of IE you are using? I still seem to have the issue. I am going to play around with it a little more, it could be an external CSS file causing the issue. I appreciate your time!

Comment: IE 11, perhaps IE could be rendering your CSS files in a different order to the other browsers? And no problem!.Sorry I couldn't offer a better solution!

Comment: Changing to percentages and added a break at the beginning of the table resolved the issue! Thank you for the help. Would have take me days to resolve haha.